# How to define a bean for an (non-static) inner class in Spring? Avoiding circular dependency

Tags: java, spring, inner-classes, circular-dependency

I am having a class with an inner class like this:

```
package myPackage;

public class A {
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) { this.b = b; }
    public B getB() { return this.b; }

    public class B {
    }
}
```

And I have my spring configuration as follow:

```
<bean id="a" class="myPackage.A" autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
    <property name="b">
        <bean class="myPackage.A$B" name="b" autowire="byName" scope="prototype">
            <constructor-arg ref="a"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I am facing this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'a': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Of course it is obvious that I am having a circular reference, but how can I have a spring bean for my inner class?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this. Maybe create a factory method instead that returns a created instance of `B`.

Comment: Is this the only way? In fact I changed `B` to static, and it resolved my problem temporarily. However; I am looking for a way to make it non-static again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this can be resolved at the Spring level if you need `a` to be scoped as prototype.  The issue is that you're trying to create an instance of `a`, which requires a reference to a `b`, which in turn is referencing a *different* instance of `a` (because prototype gives you a new instance every time you inject the bean), and so on.  If what you really want is for the `a` to be a prototype bean containing a `b` that refers to the *same* enclosing instance of `a` then you'll have to use Java config or a factory bean.

Comment: It is not an option to change the scope of `A` here. Are you suggesting that if I change the scope of `B` to `singleton` instead of `prototype`, it would resolve my issue?

Comment: @MatinKh `<bean>` definitions that are nested inside a `<property>` are always prototype.  It sounds like the easiest solution will be to use a top-level (or static nested) class for `b` rather than an inner class, and give it a `setContainingA` method that the `a` instance can call in a `@PostConstruct` method rather than trying to do the wiring at construction time.

Comment: Good point... I didn't know that. Sounds like a good plan, I'll give it a try.